# Dynamically show data in the popup which is determined in onpopupshowing event handler

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing a Firefox extension. On one `<menupopup>`, the `onpopupshowing` calls a JavaScript function. The JavaScript function extracts a list of names. Now these names have to be displayed in the same popup.

How can I get this? Basically I will need to pass the data (just as we use beans in Java) to the browser from the JavaScript function. The data can change every time the popup is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the DOM rapresenting your menupopup.
For example:

```
<menulist>
  <menupopup id="myMenuPopup">
    <menuitem id="firstItem" label="Mozilla" value="http://mozilla.org"/>
    <menuitem id="secondItem" label="Slashdot" value="http://slashdot.org"/>
    <menuitem id="thirdItem" label="Sourceforge" value="http://sf.net"/>
  </menupopup>
</menulist>
```

Now if you want to add another item:

```
var myMenuPopup = document.getElementById("myMenuPopup");
var newItem = document.createElement("menuitem");
newItem.setAttribute("id", "anotherItem");
myMenuPopup.appendChild(newItem);
```

If you want to remove an item:

```
var itemToRemove = myMenuPopup.getElementById("anotherItem");
myMenuPopup.appendChild(itemToRemove);
```

Here you can find much more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Dynamically_modifying_XUL-based_user_interface

**Edit:**

I assume thet your function returns an array of names:

```
var nameLists = yourFunction();

for (var i=0; i<nameList.length; i++){
  var newItem = document.createElement("menuitem");
  newItem.setAttribute("label", nameList[i]);
  newItem.setAttribute("id", "item" + i);
  myMenuPopup.appendChild(newItem);
}
```

I think is better if you call the function that make items **before** user click on menupopup, not on the event invocation, because if you have many items it may takes a little to construct the items list.

Comment: hey kucebe, thanks for the help. it works now. so far so good.
Now I need to have the click functionality too on these newly added menuitems. putting the atttribute and forming the function is easy. I can have a function to be run when they are clicked. But i need to pass namelist[i] to the function and it will act according to the namelist parameter.If i do:
newItem.setAttribute("oncommand" , finalclick(namelist[m]));
it runs the function everytime the popup opens runs the function without even clicking on it

Comment: on the other hand if i do
newItem.setAttribute("oncommand" , "finalclick(namelist[m])");
it doesnot open even on clicking giving error : namelist is not defined.

Comment: I think would be better if you make your event listener like this:
newItem.oncommand = function(){ finalclick(namelist[m]); }

Comment: after making this menupopup, each menu item also needs to have a popup... as in each newItem needs to have another popup.
how can i get that? [i have posted a question for the same] 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780696/ff-extension-a-popup-with-dynamic-menuitems-with-each-menu-item-having-another